# How to have emacs-helm list offer files in current directory as options?

Tags: emacs

Is there a way from the `helm-mini` command to list includes files in the current directory as part of potential search matches?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll find `helm-mini` defined as:

```
(defun helm-mini ()
  "Preconfigured `helm' lightweight version \(buffer -> recentf\)."
  (interactive)
  (helm-other-buffer '(helm-c-source-buffers-list
                       helm-c-source-recentf
                       helm-c-source-buffer-not-found)
                     "*helm mini*"))
```

so it just calls with a list of sources.  It's very easy to add any existing source.

With `helm-mode` enabled run <kbd>C-h v</kbd><kbd>helm-c-source files</kbd> (note space) and you should find:

> helm-c-source-files-in-current-dir

So make your own helm command with the sources you need:

```
(defun helm-my-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (helm-other-buffer '(helm-c-source-buffers-list
                       helm-c-source-files-in-current-dir
                       helm-c-source-recentf
                       helm-c-source-buffer-not-found)
                     "*helm-my-buffers*"))
```

Check out the definition of `helm-for-files-prefered-list` for other sources that might interest you.  And use the help system to discover new goodies.

Comment: Thanks that's very useful. I'm not 100% sure but I think that the `helm-c-source-*` variables have been renamed to `helm-source-*` in more recent versions.