# How to have emacs-helm list offer files in fixed directories as options?

Tags: emacs

This is related to this question:

[how-to-have-emacs-helm-list-offer-files-in-current-directory-as-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403862/how-to-have-emacs-helm-list-offer-files-in-current-directory-as-options)

but rather than add files from the current directory, I'd like to be able to have a fixed list of directories that helm-mini would always offer the files from. Ideally, I would like to be able to just have the files with a particular extension, and I'd like this to be done recursively (only one layer deep, in fact).

Comment: I encourage you to leverage the caching, git comprehension, native `find` integration of helm-cmd-t rather than defining your own from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.  I am using this code to list all org files in a particular directory.   If you want to list all the files, just remove the candidate-transformer line in the source, and remove the emagician/helm-ct-is-org-file.

You'll likely want to rename the source/variable/function too. ;)

**edit:** Fixed, thanks to peeking at helm-cmd-t

**note:** This is my first real crack at making a helm source, and this implementation likely sucks. It also specifically solves my problem (finding all org files in one directly only) rather then the more generalized problem  (building a helm source based on files from a particular directory).

```
(defvar emagician/helm-c-source-files
  `((name  . "Find Emagician Files")
    (header-name . (lambda (_)))
    (candidates . ,(lambda () 
                    (when (file-accessible-directory-p emagician-dir)
                      (directory-files emagician-dir t))))
    (match helm-c-match-on-file-name helm-c-match-on-directory-name)
    (keymap . ,helm-generic-files-map)
    (candidate-transformer . emagician/helm-ct-is-org-file)
    (help-message . helm-generic-file-help-message)
    (mode-line . ,helm-generic-file-mode-line-string)
    (type . file)))

(defun emagician/helm-ct-is-org-file (candidates)
  (remove-if-not (lambda (c)
                   (and (string= (substring c -4) ".org")
                        (not (string= (substring (file-name-nondirectory c) 0 2) ".#"))))
                 candidates))


(defun emagician/helm-emagician-dir () 
  "List all the org files in the Emagician dir"
  (interactive)
  (helm :sources emagician/helm-c-source-files
        :candidate-number-limit 40
        :buffer "*emagician-|-+-|-files*"))

(global-set-key (kbd "S-<f3>") 'emagician/helm-emagician-dir)
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks great! However, I'm having trouble getting it to work properly. I substituted the two instances of emagician-dir with the path to the directory I have in mind, and then emagician/helm-this-dir produces the correct-looking helm list - but when I type anything further to drill down through the filenames, all the files disappear. Also, presumably using this recursively isn't going to be easy, so I need to replace emagician-dir with a static list of subfolders to check - is that right? Thanks!

Comment: I've tried it both ways (either commenting out the (candidate-transformer . emagician/helm-ct-is-org-file) line or not), and both ways it gives the correct initial behaviour, but then both times every disappears as soon as a single character is typed.

Comment: As for a list of folders, it could be relatively simple... just (append (directory-files dir1 t) (directory-files dir2 t) (directory-files dir3 t))

Comment: Ugh. You're right about the candidates narrowing poorly.  I'll fix that nad get back to you. :/

Comment: @JonathanArkell see my answer below for using `helm-cmd-t` to do your emagician business in a simpler more powerful way. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12710093/903943

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure I like the idea of depending on the 'helm-cmd-t package.  I'd rather a solution that focuses on helm itself.  This way there is more documentation on how one should create their own sources.

Comment: @JonathanArkell Glad it was helpful.  Users shouldn't have to do as much work as you did to expose a directory or git repo as a source.  That's a problem worth solving, IMO.  Your implentation, while perfectly usable, also shows some deficiencies, which is bound to happen if everyone had to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I'll be the first to admit that this is a very cargo-cultish, specific, implementation!  I was rather surprised 9and a little dismayed) that helm doesn't come with that capacity otu of hte box.

Comment: Great - thanks to both of you. This is already a big improvement on helm for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly different take that prefilters for the org extension.

```
(require 'helm-cmd-t)

(defvar my-org-folders (list  "~/org")
  "my permanent folders for helm-mini")

(defun helm-my-org (&optional arg)
  "Use C-u arg to work with repos."
  (interactive "P")
  (if (consp arg)
      (call-interactively 'helm-cmd-t-repos)
    (let ((helm-ff-transformer-show-only-basename nil))
      (helm :sources (mapcar (lambda (dir)
                               (helm-cmd-t-get-create-source-dir dir))
                             my-org-folders)
            :candidate-number-limit 20
            :buffer "*helm-my-org:*"
            :input "org$ "))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can better solve it by leveraging the [helm-cmd-t](https://github.com/lewang/helm-cmd-t) library.  It packages
a directory recursively as repositories that you can use as a source.

It understands how to read lots of DVCS repos very fast.

The default functionality is not exactly what you are after here, but you can
easily leverage the machinery to fill all your requirements.

For example, here I define a command that adds two repos to the default
helm-mini sources.

```
(require 'helm-cmd-t)

(defvar my-mini-folders (list  "~/src/ember/data" "~/src/ember/ember.js")
  "my permanent folders for helm-mini")

(defun helm-my-mini (&optional arg)
  "my helm-mini.  Use C-u arg to work with repos."
  (interactive "P")
  (if (consp arg)
      (call-interactively 'helm-cmd-t-repos)
    (let ((helm-ff-transformer-show-only-basename nil))
      (helm :sources (nconc (list
                             helm-c-source-buffers-list
                             helm-c-source-recentf
                             helm-c-source-buffer-not-found)
                            (mapcar (lambda (dir)
                                      (helm-cmd-t-get-create-source-dir dir))
                                    my-mini-folders))
            :candidate-number-limit 20
            :buffer "*helm-my-mini:*"))))
```